# How access individual element in a tuple on a RDD in pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

Lets say I have a RDD like

`[(u'Some1', (u'ABC', 9989)),
 (u'Some2', (u'XYZ', 235)),
 (u'Some3', (u'BBB', 5379)),
 (u'Some4', (u'ABC', 5379))]`

I am using `map` to get one tuple at a time but how can I access to individual element of a tuple like to see if a tuple contains some character. Actually I want to filter out those that contains some character. Here the tuples that contain `ABC`

I was trying to do something like this but its not helping

```
def foo(line):
     if(line[1]=="ABC"):
          return (line)


new_data = data.map(foo)
```

I am new to spark and python as well please help!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

RDDs can be filtered directly. Below will give you all records that contain "ABC" in the 0th position of the 2nd element of the tuple.

```
new_data = data.filter(lambda x: x[1][0] == "ABC")
```