# Accessing individual element of a tuple on in RDD

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Can we  access individual element of a tuple in RDD in pyspark? In PIG we use $0,$1 etc ... So something similar do we have in pySpark.
If the tuple have 10 elements, how to get 5th and 7th element ? Which function I should use. How to retrieve only needed elements.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How access individual element in a tuple on a RDD in pyspark?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36629953/how-access-individual-element-in-a-tuple-on-a-rdd-in-pyspark)

Comment: Hi @JGreenwell , I checked that before posting this, thats some thing different.

Comment: What's the difference between this question and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39394826/how-to-get-specific-values-from-rdd-in-spark-with-pyspark and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39392237/how-to-add-multiple-columns-in-apache-spark . Can you try to work on some python and spark tutorials instead of asking the same question 3 times ?

Comment: @eliasah Even I thought the same. But when you check the Answer you can realize the first question's answer is not the one expected. Before asking this question I googled many ... didnt gone thru - Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
rdd57 = rdd.map(lambda x: (x[5], x[7]))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot - This was exactly the one I need